# Insert into SQL database via PHP

Tags: java, php, sql, sql-insert

My Java code produces link like this:

```
addscore.php&name=Namedd&score=0&hash=b61249d0207e4734879578733a86c3d6
```

A PHP file(addscore.php) should work with these informations and insert it into database with an sql query.

addscore.php:

```
<?php
         $db = mysql_connect("host", "root", "password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         mysql_select_db("db1") or die('Could not select database');

         $score = (int)$_GET['score'];
         $hash = $_GET['hash'];
         $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'], $db);
         $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
         $secretKey="mySecretKey";

         $real_hash = md5($score . $hash . $secretKey);

         if($real_hash == $hash) {
             $query = "INSERT INTO highscores (id, date, score, name) VALUES (NULL, '$timestamp', '$score', '$name')";
             $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
         }
?>
```

Java code gives an error message, could not submit score to server. If I try to open given url(see above) I get a `Not found` error.

**UPDATE:**
Java code:

```
        String hash = "";
        String name = nameText.getText();
        try{
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update((name + score + HASH_SALT).getBytes());
            byte byteData[] = md.digest();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            hash = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            hash = "";
        }


        try {
            String urlParameters = PARAM_NAME + name + PARAM_SCORE + score + PARAM_HASH + hash;
            URL url = new URL(HIGHSCORES_ADD + urlParameters);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.getInputStream();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Gdx.app.log( "HighScores", "Could not submit score" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
        }
```

Comment: Is the id column of the highscore table nullable ?

Comment: Shouldn't the link be `addscore.php?name...` instead of `addscore.php&name...`?

Comment: Better look to your Java code that generates the link instead. Without scrutinizing it too closely, the PHP code looks like it would work.

Comment: I have added java code.

Comment: If the id column in your database is an autoincrement integer (just guessing because those often are) you should leave it out of your INSERT query.

Comment: Yes, autoincrement field. It is working with NULL in phpmyadmin, I have tested it.

Comment: If your id field is auto increment and primary try to remove id and null parameter . leave mysql to add id value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Address should be

```
addscore.php?name=Namedd&score=0&hash=b61249d0207e4734879578733a86c3d6
```

note to first `&` in the URL

In your Java code make sure to have `?` between `HIGHSCORES_ADD` and `urlParameters`

when you fixed that if still have error in save data 
A good Idea is save your $query in a text or log file and try to check query in phpmyadmin

Another Thing you must note is 
Your insert is via php not with java ! update your question subject

Comment: I have tried this change. It gives blank screen without Query failed message. It does not add record to db.

Comment: make sure about your query with loging query in text or log file and try in phpmyadmin directly.

Comment: I have tried to save it with this:
$fp = fopen('info.txt','w');
fwrite($fp,serialize($query));
But doesn't create the output file.

Comment: `$filename = "path to your file";
$f = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($f, $query);
fclose($f);`

Comment: have you tried to remove `id` field and `null` value from `$query` ?

Comment: I have tried both. But no output in the file, so I can't log exact query.

Comment: if your `score` field type is `int` remove `single quotes` from `score` value in your query

Comment: try to use this query : `$query = "INSERT INTO highscores (date, score, name) VALUES ( '$timestamp', $score, '$name')";`

Comment: Oh, there is something wrong with HASH. It is okay now without checking HASH value.

Comment: And how should I modify Java code to use automatically ? instead of $ before name? (I have changed it manually in the test.) Thanks!

Comment: check `HIGHSCORES_ADD` last character with `string.substring(string.length() - 1)` and if not equal to `?` change your code  `HIGHSCORES_ADD + "?" + urlParameters`

Comment: also you can use `Java - String replaceFirst() Method` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replacefirst.htm

Comment: Can you please also help with HASH? $real_hash and $hash values are different.